# Getting ResourceNotFoundException when Using Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatActivity

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I am NewBie in Xamarin. I installed Android.Support.V7.App Library from Nuget Package Manager and Project builds Successfully. Now When i am extening AppCompatActivity instead of Activity than i am Getting Exception:-

```
 Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030015
```

My Activity Code is As Follows:-

```
  using Android.App;
  using Android.Widget; 
  using Android.OS; 
  using Android.Content;
  using Android.Preferences;
  using Android.Support.V7.App;

  namespace ExampleDemo
  {
[Activity(Label = "ExampleDemo", Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
         SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
    }
}
}
```

And My axml File Contains this Code:-

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
     android:id="@+id/MyButton"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/Hello"
     android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Can Anybody tell me what i am doing wrong??

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where does the exception occur? (When you scroll through the debug output you should find some more information)

Comment: Clean Solution Worked with My MainActivity. But When i Use <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout> than it gives me another Exception:- Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout @Malte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you tried **Clean the solution**? Xamarin can be stuck somewhere parsing the xml.

Comment: This Worked with My MainActivity. But When i Use    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
 than it gives me another Exception:- Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout   @nyconing

Comment: Solved....I need to add android.suppot.design Externally from Nuget Package Manager and it worked Fine....